# how to create a line in d3?

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I have managed to create a line chart in d3 but now need to overlay a couple of horizontal lines and vertical lines.  Here is what the chart looks like:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    body {
      font: 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3.5px;
    }

    .dot {
      stroke: blue;
    }

    .grid .tick {
        stroke: lightgrey;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script>
          var tests = <?php echo $tests; ?>;
          console.log("tests=" +JSON.stringify(tests));
          var events = <?php echo $events; ?>;
          console.log("events=" +JSON.stringify(events));

    var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 90},
        width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(d3.time.years,1)
        //makes the xAxis ticks a little longer than the xMinorAxis ticks
        .tickSize(10)
        .orient("bottom");

    var xMinorAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(d3.time.months,1)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.total_km); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // function for the y grid lines
    function make_y_axis() {
      return d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left")
          .ticks(5) //somehow this makes the y-axis grid draw every other line, rather than every line
    }

    var data = [];
    function DataPoint(x,y) {
        this.date_time = x;
        this.total_km = y;
    }

    var lowerLimit;
    var upperLimit;
    function loadData() {
        for (i=1; i < tests.length; i++) {
            var test = tests[i];
            console.log("x="+test[0]+", y="+test[1]);
            data.push(new DataPoint(test[0],test[1]));
            lowerLimit = test[2];
            upperLimit = test[3];
        }
    }
    loadData();
    console.log("data1="+JSON.stringify(data));

    function processData(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            console.log("d.date_time="+d.date_time +", d.total_km="+d.total_km);
            d.date = new Date(d.date_time);
            console.log("d.date=" +d.date);
        });

        //using imported data to define extent of x and y domains
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.total_km; }));

        // Draw the y Grid lines
        svg.append("g")            
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .call(make_y_axis()
                .tickSize(-width, 0, 0) //causes the line to be drawn the full width of the chart
                .tickFormat("")
            )

        //draw the data line
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);

        //draw the upper limit
        var minDate = new Date(data[0].date_time);
        console.log("minDate="+minDate +", x(minDate)="+x(minDate));
        var maxDate = new Date(data[data.length-1].date_time);
        console.log("maxDate="+maxDate +", x(maxDate)="+x(maxDate));
        svg.append("line")
            .attr("class", "x")
            .style("stroke", "red")
            .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
            .style("opacity", 0) 
            .attr("x1", x(minDate))
            .attr("y1", y(upperLimit))
            .attr("x2", x(maxDate))      
            .attr("y2", y(upperLimit));

    //creating a group(g) and will append a circle and 2 lines inside each group
    var g = svg.selectAll()
            .data(data).enter().append("g");

       //The markers on the line
         g.append("circle")
             //circle radius is increased
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.total_km); });

    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
          .selectAll(".tick text")
          .call(wrap, 35);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","xMinorAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .style({ 'stroke': 'Black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '1px'})
        .call(xMinorAxis)
        .selectAll("text").remove();

    svg.append("text")      // text label for the x-axis
            .attr("x", width / 2 )
            .attr("y",  height + margin.bottom)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Date");

    svg.append("text")      // text label for the y-axis
            .attr("y",30 - margin.left)
            .attr("x",50 - (height / 2))
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .style("font-size", "16px")
            .text("Tryglycerides (mg/dL)");

    svg.append("text")      // text label for chart Title
            .attr("x", width / 2 )
            .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top/2))
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "16px") 
            .style("text-decoration", "underline") 
            .text("Tryglyceride Levels");

    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
  };
  processData(data);
</script>
```

I want to create horizontal line at 149 for the upper limit where you want the triglyceride levels to be below.  I try to create that line in the "draw the upper limit" section.  But no line is drawn.

Comment: That's a lot of code for one person to read and figure out. Can you point out the relevant part of your code?

Comment: .attr("x2", x(maxDate))      //Error: <line> attribute x2: Expected length, "NaN".

Comment: What's the value of maxDate?

Comment: Here is the console.log statement and output:console.log("maxDate="+maxDate +", x(maxDate)="+x(maxDate));  Output: x(maxDate)=790

Comment: Why calculate the max date's scale value? The range of the scale is from `0` to `width`, where the max date is scaled to be `width`, so x2 can simply be `width`.

Comment: good point.  I changed the line to this: .attr("x2", width) but got the same error

Comment: I should note that when I click on the link in the console error message, it takes me to the attrFunction in d3.v3.js:      function attrFunction() {
      var x = value.apply(this, arguments);
      if (x == null) this.removeAttribute(name); else this.setAttribute(name, x);
    }
The red underlined error is on on "this.setAttribute(name,x);"

Comment: Not sure what is happening there - `.attr("x2", width)` looks fine, is there slim chance that the line number in your browser doesn't correspond to your php file, and the error is instead several lines down where you set x2 for another line with : `.attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d3.min(x)); })` - as this looks like it should produce an error, possibly the same error.

Comment: No, that part works fine.  I can comment out my "draw the upper limit" section of code and it all works fine without any errors.  BTW, this code comes from here: http://bl.ocks.org/d3netxer/10a28b7aee406f4e7fce which I modified to take data from a database, rather than a csv file.

Comment: Just checking all options (that line does look odd) - and if you comment out the one line throwing the error, everything still works (except the line may not be visible as x2 will equal 0)?

Comment: Hmm.  You might be onto something.  I take back what I said earlier about no errors if I comment out my "draw the upper limit" section.  I still do get the same error.  But if the error is happening further down in the code where you suspect, why am I not seeing the horizontal line at y=149?

Comment: BTW, I commented out the section you suspected, which just draws a dashed horiz and vertical line from the moused-over point, and the error went away.  So the error apparently has nothing to do with the fact that a horizontal line is not being shown at y=149 (upperLimit).

Comment: I removed a bunch of code that I now know was irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not real happy with this solution, but it works.  Could not figure out why the svg.append("line") command failed to display a line, so I used the svg.append("path") command instead.  I added the following code:

```
var data2 = [];
data2.push(new DataPoint(data[0].date_time,149));
data2.push(new DataPoint(data[data.length-1].date_time,149));
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data2)
    .attr("d", line)
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "3,3")
```

Then I modified the DataPoint code to this:

```
function DataPoint(x,y) {
    this.date_time = x;
    this.date = new Date(x);
    this.total_km = y;
}
```

Now the chart has a red dashed line representing the tryglyceride upper limit:
[image]